# competitors price analysis using Python

Tags: python, data-science

I crawled one item from more than 10 competitors. How can I find the normal price, under and overprices statistically with python?

sample data:

```
prices = [34, 33, 33.5, 47 , 33.7, 29, 20, 36, 34, 33,2]
```

Comment: Code blocks are back ticks ` not single quotes '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy is your friend! Tricky to say how to calculate under and over pricing without knowing the context but you could pick a certain number of standard deviations from the mean for this.

Similarly for normal pricing, hard to say without context but here is how you could calculate the median and mean.

I would strongly recommend you perform some general statistical analysis of the data to see how it looks - what's the distribution, are there outliers etc. before making any conclusions from this. I would also suggest you come up with a robust methodology for calculating over/underpricing before taking decisions based on this. Please take the below just as brief examples of how to implement statistical concepts in numpy...

```
import numpy as np

prices = [34, 33, 33.5, 47 , 33.7, 29, 20, 36, 34, 33,2]
mean = np.mean(prices)
median = np.median(prices)
stdev = np.std(prices)

## Let's say you decide more than 1 stdev +- from the mean is over/undepricing
overpricing_threshold = mean + stdev
underpricing_threshold = mean - stdev
print(mean)
print(median)
print(stdev)
print(overpricing_threshold)
print(underpricing_threshold)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest diving into basic machine learning with [Scikit Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/). You could utilize a simple [Linear Regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) with your task. Or if you are a bit enthusiastic even an [XGBoost Regressor](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) will do the trick.

Approaching this problem with Machine Learning can give a better insight as to what is the "normal price".